# JQuery Ajax/PHP GET on Anchor

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a table with record and a delete button. Each delete button has an id and I press the button to delete the record.

Code below:

```
echo '<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id='.$id.'">Delete</a></td>';
```

output html:

```
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=1">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=2">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=3">Delete</a>
<a class="delete" href="delete.php?id=4">Delete</a>
```

Delete.php:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($_GET['messageid']))
{

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE from table WHERE id='$id'");

mysqli_close($con); 


}

?>
```

The code above works as intended but I don't want to have to browse to the other page so I was thinking JQuery Ajax.
I know how to use jquery ajax for forms but this is not the case.
How can I get JQuery Ajax to work with my code?

Comment: You should not use a `GET` to perform a delete operation - use a `POST` as a bare minimum [though you wont' achieve that with a plain href of course].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as an option you could bind Ajax requests to your links like this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('a.delete').click(function(){
        $.get(
            $(this).attr('href'),
            {},
            function(data) {
                alert('Deleted');
            },
            'html'
        );
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Inside this anonymous function you can use any logic instead of **alert()** to show that record has been deleted (delete the link for instance). Or you can change your PHP script to return some JSON answer and parse it with this function. Its up to you.

And of course you have vulnerability in your sql query, you should at least use

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;
if ($id) {
```

This will avoid notice if $_GET['id'] is not set and will secure your query.
Moreover, consider POST method for deleting.